# Cannot access Hive via PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, pyspark

I am new to Hadoop/Spark/Hive!

I have created a single node linux (Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS) VM running locally with the following; Hadoop 3.1.0; Spark: Spark 2.3.1, Hive: Hive-3.0.0

My Hive is using the standard Derby DB and I can access hive through the terminal and create databases, tables and then query these tables fine. My metastore_db is located at ~/hivemetastore/metastore_db

I also have also created the following:

hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/hive/warehouse

hadoop fs -mkdir -p /tmp/hive

(Note- I do not have any hive-site.xml files under $HIVE_HOME/conf or $SPARK_HOME/conf)

However when I try to read a hive table from pyspark (via terminal), I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 710, in sql return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
File "/usr/local/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
File "/usr/local/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69, in decoraise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient;'
```

The code I am using to access hive from pyspark is:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
spark.sql('show databases').show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you start the metastore?

Type:

```
hive --service metastore
```

Remove the lock using **rm metastore_db/*.lck** or restart the system (or the PySpark shell).

Comment: I deleted the lock files and then tried to run hive --service metastore however it just seems to hang on that command and nothing happens

Comment: Did you run it as su hive --service metastore
And you said you are trying to read a hive table but, you typed in 'show databases'?

Comment: Can you post in the screenshot?

Comment: Same issue with reading table or trying to execute any hiveql

Comment: This is my terminal:

hduser@ismail-VirtualBox:~/hivemetastore$ hive --service metastore
2018-10-03 21:32:35: Starting Hive Metastore Server
^C
hduser@ismail-VirtualBox:~/hivemetastore$ service hive-metastore start
Failed to start hive-metastore.service: Unit hive-metastore.service not found.
hduser@ismail-VirtualBox:~/hivemetastore$

Comment: Can you try this in PySpark?
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
sqlContext.sql('show databases').show()

Comment: Still getting the same error mentioned in the original question

Comment: Exclude these two lines:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

Comment: Yep I had excluded these lines too. Do you think a fresh install of Hive may be the solution? If so do you know any good documentation that can take me through the installation and configuration (with Spark)?

Comment: Can you add this in hive-site.xml?
<configuration>
    <property>
      <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
      <value>thrift://sandbox.hortonworks.com:9083</value>
    </property>
  </configuration>